# Why does this JavaFX tab pane example not work?

Tags: javafx

My MainApp:

```
package multitabpane;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

public class MainApp extends Application 
{
  private Stage primaryStage;
  private AnchorPane rootLayout;  

 /** The horizontal offset for making the rootLayout movable */
  private double xOffset = 0;
 /** The vertical offset for making the rootLayout movable */  
  private double yOffset = 0;

  public MainApp() {}

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage){
    this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
    //Get rid of the windoze crap
    primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
    initRootLayout();
    //Make the screen movable by a drag and drop 
    rootLayout.setOnMousePressed((MouseEvent event) -> {
      xOffset = event.getSceneX();
      yOffset = event.getSceneY();
    });
    rootLayout.setOnMouseDragged((MouseEvent event) -> {
      primaryStage.setX(event.getScreenX() - xOffset);
      primaryStage.setY(event.getScreenY() - yOffset);
    });

  }

 /**
  * Initializes the root layout.
  */
  public void initRootLayout() 
  {
    try 
    {
      // Load root layout from fxml file.
      FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
     Loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("view/MainController.fxml"));
      rootLayout = (AnchorPane)loader.load();
      // Show the scene containing the root layout.
      Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
      primaryStage.setScene(scene);
      primaryStage.show();
    } catch (IOException e) {}
  }

 /**
  * Returns the main stage.
  * @return
  */
  public Stage getPrimaryStage() {
    return primaryStage;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){
    launch(args);
  }
    }
```

Here's the MainController.java and MainController.xml

```
package multitabpane.view;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;

public class MainController {
  // Inject tab content.
    @FXML private AnchorPane fooTabPage;
// Inject controller
    @FXML private FooTabController fooTabPageController;
// Inject tab content. Keep Commented out until the above is working
//    @FXML private BarTabPage barTabPage;
    // Inject controller 
//    @FXML private BarTabController barTabPageController;
}
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
 <TabPane id="tabPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0">
    <tabs>
        <Tab text="Tab 1">
            <content>
              <fx:include fx:id="fooTabPage" source="fooTabPage.fxml"/>
            </content>
        </Tab>
        <Tab text="Tab 2">
            <content>
              <!-- commented out until I can get the above to work -->
              <!-- fx:include fx:id="barTabPage" source="barTabPage.fxml"/ -->
            </content>
        </Tab>
    </tabs>
</TabPane>  
</AnchorPane>
```

Here's the FooTabController:

```
package multitabpane.view;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;

class FooTabController {
  @FXML private AnchorPane fooTabPage;
}
```

Finally this is the FooTabPage.java and xml:

```
package multitabpane.view;

class FooTabPage {}
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

    <AnchorPane fx:id="fooTabPage" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2" fx:controller="multitabpane.view.FooTabController" />
```

And finally is the dump when I try and run the built project:

```
Executing D:\J2EE\MultiTabPane\dist\run679227950\MultiTabPane.jar using platform C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre/bin/java
Jun 21, 2017 9:14:22 AM multitabpane.MainApp initRootLayout
Error in MainApp:initRootLayout()
SEVERE: null
file:/D:/J2EE/MultiTabPane/dist/run679227950/MultiTabPane.jar!/multitabpane/view/fooTabPage.fxml:9
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
file:/D:/J2EE/MultiTabPane/dist/run679227950/MultiTabPane.jar!/multitabpane/view/MainController.fxml:14
```

file:/D:/J2EE/MultiTabPane/dist/run679227950/MultiTabPane.jar!/multitabpane/view/fooTabPage.fxml:9
file:/D:/J2EE/MultiTabPane/dist/run679227950/MultiTabPane.jar!/multitabpane/view/MainController.fxml:14

```
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$700(FXMLLoader.java:103)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:934)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:971)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:220)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:744)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$2700(FXMLLoader.java:103)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$IncludeElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1143)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:746)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)
at multitabpane.MainApp.initRootLayout(MainApp.java:58)
at multitabpane.MainApp.start(MainApp.java:35)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$163(LauncherImpl.java:863)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$176(PlatformImpl.java:326)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$174(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$175(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$149(WinApplication.java:191)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)



 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil can not access a member of class   multitabpane.view.FooTabController with modifiers ""
        at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Reflection.java:102)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:436)
        at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.newInstance(ReflectUtil.java:51)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:927)
        ... 24 more
```

Comment: The exception is saying that the element in `MainController.fxml` with `fx:id = "fooTabPage"` is an `AnchorPane`: you are trying to assign it (via `@FXML` injection) to a variable of type `FooTabPage`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I simply can't see what I need to do.

Comment: Does this mean that in the MainApp class the coderootLayout = (AnchorPane) loader.load(); is wrong?

Comment: No, it means exactly what I said in the first comment. Your controller has `@FXML private FooTabPage fooTabPage ;` but the thing you called `fooTabPage` in the FXML file is an `AnchorPane`, not a `FooTabPage`.

Comment: But when you create an FMXL file in Netbeans it sort of forces you into using an anchorpane. I think a good workaround would be to use a Button instead of a Tab and then adapt the css to make it look like a tab and then use hbox to make the buttons look like tabs. Ive used buttons like this before to implement a desktop application where a user needs to have an entry point to an app that has a number of differerent 'branches'. Im not sure if tab panes are implementable at all in JavaFX. In Swing it seemed so easy.

Comment: So if it's an anchor pane, change the type of the injected field in the controller to `AnchorPane`. I don't use NetBeans, but I simply don't believe that it doesn't allow you to use a root different to an anchor pane.

Comment: @James_D In NB using **New > Empty FXML** an FXML automatically creates:'< AnchorPane id="AnchorPane"></AnchorPane>' A click on the FXML opens Scene Builder to add containers and controls. If  manually edited to replace 'AnchorPane' with 'TabPane' and then try and open the Scene Builder, you get _Loading of the file "MainController.fxml" has failed .. make sure it is a valid FXML file.. So you are no  longer to use the Scene Builder to do anything.

Comment: When editing it, are you fixing the imports too? What if you open it and then remove the Anchor pane in scene builder (instead of manually editing it)? Also, have you tried replacing the anchor pane with a different layout pane?

Comment: @yab the mc looks like this:

Comment: You are still completely missing the point though. If you define something in the FXML file with a `fx:id` then the field in the controller with the matching name will be set to that FXML element. So the types of the things must match. If the thing in the FXML file is an `AnchorPane`, the corresponding thing in the controller cannot be a `FooTabPage`. It doesn't matter whether you change the FXML file or change the controller, the two things **must** have the same type.

Comment: But I am doing this. In fooTabPage I have set via SB 'fx:id' to 'fooTabPage' and 'Controller class' to 'FooTabController'. In FooTabController I have '@FXML private FooTabPage; In MainController.fxml I have '<fx:include fx:id="fooTabPage" source="fooTabPage.fxml"' What more does it want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem by changing the 'foo' references in the sample code with more meaningful names based on 'tab1' and 'tab2'. I don't get errors when I run the build project now:

The main controller declares references to the tabs:

```
public class MainController {
   @FXML private AnchorPane tab1Page;   
   @FXML private AnchorPane tab2Page;
}
```

In the main controller fxml bind the tab references to their file sources:

```
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2" fx:controller="multitabpane.view.MainController">
  <TabPane id="tabPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0">
    <tabs>
      <Tab text="Tab 1">
        <content>
          <fx:include fx:id="tab1Page" source="Tab1Controller.fxml"/>
        </content>
      </Tab>
      <Tab text="Tab 2">
        <content>
          <fx:include fx:id="tab2Page" source="Tab2Controller.fxml"/>
        </content>
      </Tab>
    </tabs>
  </TabPane>
</AnchorPane>
```

In the tab controller classes create reference for the tab and references to any other controls that the work area of the tab that the user defines. In my solution there is a button in each tabs control heirarchy and a listener for button 'On Action' commands:

```
public class Tab1Controller {
  @FXML Tab tab1; 
  @FXML Button exitButton;  

  @FXML
  public void exitApp()
  {
    System.exit(1);
  }
}
```

and

```
public class Tab2Controller 
{
  @FXML Tab tab2;
  @FXML Button resetButton;

  @FXML
  public void handleReset()
  {
    System.out.println("Does nothing");
  }
}
```

The tab controllers have to reference their controllers accordingly:

```
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2" fx:controller="multitabpane.view.Tab1Controller">
  <children>
    <Button fx:id="exitButton" layoutX="92.0" layoutY="136.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#exitApp" text="Button" />
  </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

and

```
 <AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2" fx:controller="multitabpane.view.Tab2Controller">
  <children>
    <Button fx:id="resetButton" layoutX="78.0" layoutY="180.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleReset" text="Reset" />
  </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

In summary there is a MainApp, three controller classes and 3 corresponding FXML views.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem probably because in the class MainController, you declare fooTabPage as an instance of FooTabPage, but in the MainController.fxml, you use `<AnchorPane fx:id="fooTabPage">`, in short, you declare difference type of fooTabPage in the fxml and java class.

Just change the code

```
"@FXML private FooTabPage fooTabPage;"
```

to

```
"@FXML private AnchorPane fooTabPage;"
```

in MainController, the problem will be solved.
Because in your "fooTabPage.fxml", it's root element is AnchorPane, you should declare the same type with what you use in fxml root pane.

Comment: Ill do that, unfortunately travelling across continents this weekend but Ill do that when I get back to my desk.

Comment: <AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0">
 <TabPane id="tabPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0">
    <tabs>
        <Tab text="Tab 1">
            <content>
              <fx:include fx:id="fooTabPage" source="fooTabPage.fxml"/>
            </content>
        </Tab>
        <Tab text="Tab 2">
            <content>
              <!-- commented out until I can get the above to work -->
            </content>
        </Tab>
    </tabs>
</TabPane>  
</AnchorPane>

Comment: can you post the content of fooTabPage.fxml too? because i guess the problem is on the root element of fooTabPage.fxml.

Comment: don't worry, i'll try my best to figure out the problem with u as long as you provide enough clues.

Comment: hi @Rusty, you said "In FooTabController I have '@FXML private FooTabPage", but do you have a real java class name FooTabPage?
i think the problem is, you should not use "@FXML private FooTabPage fooTabPage;" in your MainController. Just change the code
"@FXML private FooTabPage fooTabPage;"
to
"@FXML private AnchorPane fooTabPage;"
in MainController, the problem will be solved.

Comment: Hello @yab thanks for your patience. I have edited the original code examples to include everything that is relevant.